# Dropdown lists that update values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to create a Sheets that allows me to change the day and store all the information about it like if it was another page. Something like this:
[image: Example]

The idea is to be able to fill the cells and change the day (top left) to get the same but empty to continue filling

Comment: If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. These are different apps with different functionality, even though there is some file compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `onEdit` trigger

Upon change of `A3`:

1. copy the values to the sheet named as the value of `A3`
2. clear the values in `B6:F`